# Migrate Spring Security from 5 to 6

Tags: spring-security

We are currently having:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class OpenApiSecurityConfig() : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
            http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/docs")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(MyApiFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor::class.java)
    }
}
```

And according to docs, this should be replaced with `SecurityFilterChain` bean:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    open fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
            http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/docs")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(MyApiFilter(), AuthorizationFilter::class.java)
    }
```

However the HttpSecurity object has completely changed and the `requestMatchers()` is missing and I couldn't find a specification how to perform the migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `securityMatcher("/docs")` to apply your filter

> Allows configuring the HttpSecurity to only be invoked when matching the provided pattern. This method **creates a MvcRequestMatcher if Spring MVC is in the classpath** or creates an **AntPathRequestMatcher if not**. If more advanced configuration is necessary, consider using securityMatchers(Customizer) or securityMatcher(RequestMatcher)

```kotlin
@Bean
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
   return http
            .securityMatcher("/docs") 
            .addFilterBefore(MyApiFilter(), AuthorizationFilter::class.java)
            .build()
}
```